# Free group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, gap

I know that in the free group $F$ with two generators $x$ and $y$, there is some word $w \in [F,F]$ such that $xy^2=x^{-2} y^{-3} x^{-2}(xy)^5 w$.
Is it possible to find $w$ using GAP?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, then there is a GAP Forum mailing list which you could try.

Comment: GAP functionality which is useful for writing such program is demonstrated here: http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2015/004983.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want some expression of $w$ as a product of commutators, then that is not difficult. As I am sure you know, for any element $w$ in a free group $F$, $w \in [F,F]$ if and only if the exponent sum of each of its generators is $0$.

So suppose that $w \in [F,F]$ and let $x$ be its first letter. Then $x^{-1}$ must also occur in $w$, so $w = xux^{-1}v$ for some $u,v \in F$, and hence $w = (xux^{-1}u^{-1})(uv)$ and it suffices to express $uv$ as product of commutators. Since the length of $uv$ is two less than that of $w$, this process terminates. You could certainly do that calculation in GAP. The resulting expression as a product of commutators would have length at most $l(w)/2$.

If you were looking for a word that was the product of the smallest possible number of commutators (or even a close a approximation to that), then that might be a lot harder, and I can only think of very naive brute force approaches to that, which would be impractical for long words.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recent [preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.04261.pdf) By Fialkovski and Ivanov that describes an algorithm for computing the commutator length of an element in a free group, and it also gives a minimal commutator representation of an element in $F'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear Primoz, but the first algorithm is much more effective for my purpose.

Comment: Note that the authors claim to have an implementation in GAP.